# How to fix "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource" in Angular/.NET Project

Tags: c#, .net, angular

When I submit a HTTP GET request to our API endpoints, I get errors saying that the CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing.

We have a SQL Server database connected to a .NET API with an Angular 7 front end.

This is the Angular service that submits the request

```
public VALUES_API_ENDPOINT = 'http://localhost:53273/api/search';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  async queryResults(terms: string): Promise<any> {
    try {
      const result = await this.httpClient.get(this.VALUES_API_ENDPOINT + '/title/' + terms).toPromise();
      return result;
    } catch (error) {
        await this.handleError(error);
    }
  }
```

And the backend controller call looks like this:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("title")]
public HttpResponseMessage SearchByTitle(string s)
{
   HttpResponseMessage response;
   try
   {
       List<Regulation> results = search.SearchRegulationByTitle(s);
       string json = CondensedRegulationsToJson(results);
       response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
       response.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
       response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
   }
   return response;
}
```

Our API Configuration looks like this:

```cs
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
   // Web API configuration and services
   // Web API routes

   config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "DefaultApi",
         routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
         defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
   );

   // Enable CORS for the Angular App
   // NOTE: Since we are running both the frontend and the backend locally, we can trust this origin with all headers and methods (the *). In practice, we would only allow really needed headers and methods
    config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:4200", "*", "*", "*"));

  // Make JSON the default formatter over XML
  config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
}
```

We should be receiving things from the database, but we just get denied access instead based on the CORS attributes.

EDIT:
The error log from the web console follows:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:53273/api/search/title/new/tax
Request method:GET
Remote address:127.0.0.1:53273
Status code:
404
Version:HTTP/1.1
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Response Headers:

```
Cache-Control   
private
Content-Length  
4966
Content-Type    
text/html; charset=utf-8
Date    
Mon, 01 Apr 2019 17:26:39 GMT
Server  
Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By    
ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles   
=?UTF-8?B?QzpcR2l0SHViXFNwcmlu…2VhcmNoXHRpdGxlXG5ld1x0YXg=?=
```

Request Headers:

```
Accept  
application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate
Accept-Language 
en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection  
keep-alive
Host    
localhost:53273
Origin  
http://localhost:4200
Referer 
http://localhost:4200/
User-Agent  
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0
```

The full CORS error I got is as follows:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:53273/api/search/title/new/tax. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

Comment: So you are calling the backend api from site on port 4200 to port 53273, can you show the network log details of the failed request in your browser?

Comment: [Zhao Hainan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1350922/zhao-hainan) are the error logs I added the right thing? I'm new to web dev, so I'm not positive exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your api url is incorrect:

You have additional `/new/` causing 404 error. Take out the `/new` from api url and issue should be resolved.

```
 const result = await this.httpClient.get(this.VALUES_API_ENDPOINT + '/title/' + terms).toPromise();
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I tried making a similar API endpoint under /title/new/, however, neither that nor /title/ works. To make sure that it wasn't the issue, I changed it, but I get the same error logs. I'll change the question to ensure this is reflected.

Comment: So your issue is caused due to invalid api url. Do you any attribute applied at the controller class level? Please share that as well.

Comment: Do you mean things like the ```[Route("title")]``` or ```[HttpGet]``` that goes before the controller method?

Comment: Still getting the same error. Is the problem that the API is bad, if none of the URLs are working?

Comment: Yes the api endpoint is not accessible somehow. Do you have any `RoutePrefix` defined inside SearchController class?

Comment: Apart from the ```config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );``` line that I sent already, no

Comment: May be this article can help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#why-attribute-routing

Comment: In my case I was calling the API with http when the site was running under https.